# Javascript change background color function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, animation, structure

So I am trying to change the background color of a div using animate so that the background color changes gradually not instantly.

I have tried the piece of code below but to no avail, and i feel this would be the best way to structure the code but it just doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var array = ["red", "pink", "orange", "black"];

   var counter = 0;
   var nextColor;

   function bgchange() {
     counter = (counter + 1) % array.length;
     nextColor = array[counter];

     $("#box").animate({
       background - color: nextColor
     }, 3000);

   }

   setInterval(bgchange, 3000)


 });
```

I finally used a different approach to get this done but it does not seem
to be super efficient just by looking at it

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(function() {

    $('#box')
      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'red' }, 3000)
      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'pink' }, 3000)
      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'orange' }, 3000)
      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'black' }, 3000);
  }, 3000);

});
```

This second example works but will this piece of code be making multiple call backs to get the next color?? I assume an array is better but I am not sure what the best practice is here, and is my first example possible to fix to get working?

Comment: You can't animate the color with jQuery (-> [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties)). You need jQueryUI or any other plugin/library/own code to achieve this with Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can do background-color fades via CSS - but don't forget that older browsers will not support this.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
var colorArray = ["red", "pink", "orange", "black"];
var currentColorIndex = 0;
setInterval(function() {
$('#box').css('backgroundColor', colorArray[currentColorIndex]);
  currentColorIndex++;
}, 3000);
  
});
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: #F5DEB3;
     -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">Examplecontent</div>
```

[DEMO via Liveweave.com](http://liveweave.com/fEOIGp)

Answer (score 2):

As noted before, jQuery does not support color animation but I suppose that if you succeed to make it work with your later example, you are using a plugin such as jQuery UI.

jQuery's `animate` calls are piped so you do not have to wait for the end of the previous animation before adding a new one. As soon as an animation ends, the next animation will start.

You later example is OK **except** that you are piping new animations faster than they are actually consumed: Your 4 animations take 3 x 4 = 12s to complete while you are adding another round every 3 seconds. As a result you will end up with a very long animation queue which will unnecessary use more and more memory. Here is a fix:

**Without array and with jQuery UI.**

Instead of calculating yourself when the animation is supposed to end, you may do better by providing `bgChange` as a `complete` callback to your last `animate` call.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function bgChange(){
    $('#box')
      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'red' }, 3000)
      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }, 3000)
      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'blue' }, 3000)
      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'black' }, {
         duration: 3000,
         complete: bgChange // Loop !
      });
  }
  // Start the animation.
  bgChange();

});
```

```css
#box{
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="box"></div>
```

**With an array and jQuery UI.**

If you want to use an array, I would do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var array = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "black"];
  var box = $("#box");
  function bgChange(){
    // Create all animations.
    array.forEach(function(color){
      box.animate({
        "background-color": color
      }, 3000);
    });
    // box.promise() returns a promise resolved when all box's animations
    // are finished (i.e. then's callback will be called).
    return box.promise().then(bgChange);
  }
  // Start !
  bgChange();
});
```

```css
#box{
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="box"></div>
```

**With CSS animation** (preferred method).

It is more efficient to use css animations rather than jQuery `animate`. You can do things like:

```css
#box{
    height: 50px;
    animation: background 9s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear; /* though you may choose another easing function */
}

@keyframes background {
    0%   {background-color: red;}
    25%  {background-color: blue;}
    75%  {background-color: yellow;}
    100% {background-color: red;}
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

You may need to add css prefixes for some browser (i.e. `-webkit-` for Safari's older versions).

**With CSS transition.**

If you still want the different colors to be javascript controlled, you can also use CSS transitions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = ["red", "blue", "pink", "yellow"];
  var box = $("#box");
  var current = 0;
  function bgChange(){
    box.css("background-color", colors[current]);
    current = (current + 1) % colors.length;
  }
  // Goes to next background each time a transition ends
  // (i.e. current background has finished to fade in).
  box.on("transitionend", bgChange);
  // Launch the first animation.
  bgChange();
});
```

```css
#box{
  height: 50px;
  transition: background-color 3s linear; /* once again it does not have to be linear */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Once again you may want to use `-webkit-transition` rule and listen for `-webkit-transitionend` events in addition as Safari just released his non prefixed animation support.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var array = ["red", "pink", "orange", "black"];

var counter = 0;
var nextColor;

function  bgchange() {
counter = (counter + 1) % array.length;
nextColor = array[counter];

$("#box").animate( { background-color: nextColor}, 3000, bgchange);

}
bgchange();


});
```

If you add function name as parameter for animate(). This function will be invoked after animation ends.